# Why does the intersection of prime ideals uniquely determine the prime ideals?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

For context, I'm going through an introductory course in algebraic geometry. The course is such that it doesn't assume any commutative algebra knowledge so many results are taken on belief, but on the other hand we spend some time proving small results to get a feel for things.

**Claim:** Let $P_1, \ldots, P_k$ be prime ideals where $i \neq j \implies P_i \nsubseteq P_j$. A finite intersection of prime ideals $I = \bigcap \limits^k_{i=1} P_i$ uniquely determines the set of prime ideals $\{P_1, \ldots, P_k\}$ which $I$ is an intersection of.

**Attempt:** The key idea is to use prime avoidance lemma, but I have no clue how it is applied here. It is supposed to be used as follows. Say we have another way to write the intersection with some other prime ideals: $I = \bigcap\limits^l_{i=1}Q_i$. We see that $\bigcap \limits^l_{i=1}Q_i \subseteq P_1$, so supposedly now prime avoidance lemma implies that there exists $Q_j$ such that $Q_j \subseteq P_1$. Buying this result, the claim follows easily, but I cannot for the life of me prove this by using prime avoidance lemma.

I think that a way to show this without using the prime avoidance lemma is by noticing that $Q_1\cdots Q_l \subseteq \bigcap\limits^l_{i=1}Q_i \subseteq P_1$. Then, since $P_1$ is prime, it follows that $\exists j: Q_j \subseteq P_1$ and we are done.

A search online has yielded either extensive articles on commutative algebra or proofs of prime avoidance lemma, which is not what I am looking for. I also haven't studied commutative algebra in an organized way yet, I will do so next semester, so I have no way with textbooks like Atiyah or Eisenbud to find what I am looking for.

I spent more than an hour proving this and trying to find a way to use prime avoidance lemma, but it would seem that I am missing some obvious detail and I will probably hate myself for spending too much time on a triviality like this.

Just hints would be most appreciated.

Comment: See Proposition 1.11. (ii) in Atiyah-Macdonald. The proof is essentially the same as yours. FWIW, prime avoidance lemma appears as Proposition 1.11. (i) in Atiyah-Macdonald.

Comment: Why is the key idea to use prime avoidance? As you began to show, the proof is a couple lines long and only invokes the definition of a prime ideal.